# Событие ng-click на angular

Tags: angularjs, события

Изучаю js фреймворк Angular. Используя дерективу `ng-click` - хочу получить объект события (по которому кликнули)
Я знаю что на jQquery используют `$(this)`. Но как на angular обращаться к объекту события удобным решением?

```
categoriesApp.controller('categoriesController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.post('/user/GetCats').success(function(data){
    $scope.categories = data;
  });

  $scope.show = function() {
    if($(this).hasClass()) {
      //.......some code
    }
  } 
});
```

```
<input type="text" class="for-open-in53" placeholder="Укажите специализацию" ng-click="show($event)">
```

Comment: ```$scope.show = function(e){}``` в аргумент будет передаваться DOM, как я понимаю. Либо объект у которого есть ссылка на него. Например, ```e.target```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все манипуляции с DOM в Angularjs следует осуществлять через директивы:

```
app.directive('someDirName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click',function(){
                // элемент события ↓
                console.log( element );
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
$scope.show = function(e){
    console.log(e)
    $(e.currentTarget).html('Дед Мороз')
}
```

**e** - объект события

**e.currentTarget** - DOM объекта события

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click="handler($event)` - передаем объект события ($event) в HTML

```
$scope.handler = function(event) 
  {
    var animation = 'fadeInLeft';
    //console.log(event);   - смотрим что от него нам надо 
    $(event.target).removeClass()..... и можно так
```